# jnlp file reports and error

Tags: java, jnlp

I have been watching these tutorials from MIT on Artificial Intelligence. The instructor Patrick Winston shows a demonstrator where there are different applications based on AI. The demonstrator file is available for download. It is a .jnlp file.
             When I downloaded the file and ran it, it gave me this error, "jar files in jnlp are not signed by same certificate". Now i have tried many things after Googling like clearing the cache, removing the applications and applets from java control panel. Sadly nothing worked. The demonstrator is available here: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-034-artificial-intelligence-fall-2010/demonstrations/ Can anyone help!

Comment: Security rules have been tightened since 2010. Have you tried adding the site to your security exception list in the Java Control Panel?

Comment: The website is listed in the trusted certificates menu. Is that what you have asked? @assylias

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: I have Java version 7 @assylias

Comment: You would require jdk 1.7+

Comment: To execute jnlp files locally the jars they refer must be signed.

Comment: Is that something that i got to do myself or it should come with the file i downloaded? @DarshanLila

Comment: It has to be done by host of jnlp files.